# Open ViewPager with PagerAdapter in a specific position based on the clicked item in RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

I have a chat application with Firestore, and I put the sent image messages in a ViewPager adapter. So, I succeeded in viewing all image messages between the sender and receiver. But, the problem is, when clicking on any image inside the chat room, the ViewPager starts at the same position [0].

I want the adapter to listen to my click on an item and go to the target position. Here is my ViewPager adapter and some code samples.

```
class ImgViewPagerAdapter(val context: Context, private val imageList: ArrayList<ImageViewerData>)
    : PagerAdapter(){

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return imageList.size
    }

    override fun isViewFromObject(view: View, `object`: Any): Boolean {
        return view === `object` as RelativeLayout
    }

    override fun instantiateItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int): Any {
        val mLayoutInflater =
            context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater

        val itemView: View = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.img_viewer_item, container, false)

        val imageView: ImageView = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.idIVImage) as ImageView

        val currentImg = imageList[position]
        Glide.with(context).load(currentImg.img).into(imageView)

        Objects.requireNonNull(container).addView(itemView)

        return itemView
    }

    override fun destroyItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int, `object`: Any) {
        container.removeView(`object` as RelativeLayout)
    }

}
```

```
firestore.collection("Chats").document(senderRoom).collection("messages")
            .whereEqualTo("type", "photo").addSnapshotListener { value, _ ->
                if (!value?.isEmpty!!) {
                    for (document in value.documents) {
                        val img = document.data?.get("message").toString()
                        val senderName = document.data?.get("senderName").toString()
                        imageList.add(ImageViewerData("", img, "", senderName))
                        viewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    }
                }
            }
```

```
class ImageViewerData(var imgId: String, var img: String, var imgDate: String, var imgSender: String)
```

Here, i want to pass an id for every inserted image; the id starts at 0 and auto-increments with every sent or received image.

```
private val startForProfileImageResult =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result: ActivityResult ->
            val resultCode = result.resultCode
            val data = result.data

            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                //Image Uri will not be null for RESULT_OK
                val fileUri = data?.data!!

                imgUri = fileUri
                if (imgUri != null) {
                    val reference = storage.reference.child("Chats").child(senderRoom!!)
                        .child("Image Messages").child(senderUid!!)
                    val reference2 = storage.reference.child("Chats").child(receiverRoom!!)
                        .child("Image Messages").child(senderUid!!)
                    reference.putFile(imgUri!!).addOnCompleteListener { task->
                        reference2.putFile(imgUri!!)
                        if (task.isSuccessful) {
                            reference.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener { uri->
                                imgMsg = uri.toString()
                                val date = Date()
                                val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
                                val day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)
                                var currentDay = ""
                                when (day) {
                                    Calendar.SUNDAY-> { currentDay = "Sunday" }
                                    Calendar.MONDAY-> { currentDay = "Monday" }
                                    Calendar.TUESDAY-> { currentDay = "Tuesday" }
                                    Calendar.WEDNESDAY-> { currentDay = "Wednesday" }
                                    Calendar.THURSDAY-> { currentDay = "Thursday" }
                                    Calendar.FRIDAY-> { currentDay = "Friday" }
                                    Calendar.SATURDAY-> { currentDay = "Saturday" }
                                }
                                val imageMsg = hashMapOf("message" to imgMsg, "senderId" to senderUid!!, "date" to calendar,
                                    "time" to date, "day" to currentDay, "seen" to "false", "type" to "photo")
                                firestore.collection("Chats").document(senderRoom!!)
                                    .collection("messages")
                                    .add(imageMsg).addOnSuccessListener {
                                        firestore.collection("Chats").document(receiverRoom!!)
                                            .collection("messages").add(imageMsg)
                                            .addOnSuccessListener {  }
                                            .addOnFailureListener {
                                                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                                            }
                                    }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

I tried to put an incremental infinite method for the inserted images in Firestore, but it always puts the same id value (0). If possible or available in Firestore, how to put an integer value for each image that starts at 0.

Thank you...

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by calling setCurrenItem of the view pager:

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem(index);
```

Quick tip: you'd better use ViewPager2, it will be much easier for you.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use ViewPager2. I already used this method but what i want here is to put indicators for every retrieved image from Firestore.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to show the index of the image? Ex: 1, 2, 3? You can pass index into ImageViewerData data class.
Can you show the code?

Comment: I attached the code sample for adding image messages to the Firestore database.